# listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Tags: node.js, npm

In my application, I use concurrently to run both backend and front end simultaneously. After ctrl + c, strill the port 5000 is running. Also, port 3000 is running. I have to manually kill processes. How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you use to start the server?

Comment: I use this script.  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Run cmd.exe as 'Administrator':

C:\Windows\System32>taskkill /F /IM node.exe

Answer (score 0):

run `pa -xa | grep node`

you will get result with processid

```
4476 pts/0    Sl+    0:01 node index.js
```

then kill the process with `kill -9 4476`

as simple as that

Comment: it says `pa not found`

Answer (score 0):

lsof -ti finds open files(sockets are files in nix based systems) -t removes the headers, so that we can pipe into kill(We just want the process id), -i lets lsof find the file based off the internet address. We do not have to provide the full address, we can just search by port, by using the pattern :port.

Some commands accept input from stdin, and we can pipe directly to them, kill is not one of those commands, so we must use xargs(It reads from stdin, and calls the specified command with the input from stdin).

Finally the ; lets us execute both commands irrespective of one another. Regardless of whether lsof -ti:3000 | xargs kill succeeds or fails, 
lsof -ti:5000 | xargs kill will run, and vice versa.

```
lsof -ti:3000 | xargs kill; lsof -ti:5000 | xargs kill
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your laptop/server, it will release all the busy ports, then try again... you can also use

```
ps aux | grep node
```

and then kill the process using:

```
kill -9 PID..
```

You can kill all the processes that are using node it can also kill a system process

Not preferred: `killall -9 node`

but most of the times it wont work for nodemon, and didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue by killing the address in use or may simply restart your device.

1- For Linux to Kill the address in use, use the following command

```
sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)
```

where replace 8080 with your app address.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply   restart your laptop or change the port number it should work